# Alamofire completionHandler updating ui works only when function finishes

Tags: ios, swift3, alamofire

I use Alamofire 4.4. I update UI inside completionHandler of Alamofire but it doesn't get updated until function finishes. I use `sleep(10)` for testing. UI updates only after 10 seconds. But I need it to update at the beginning.

Shortly. I perform some operations in completionHandler and it takes some time. About 10 seconds. I want to show percentage of completion of process. But UI doesn't get updated. For example: At the beginning of the process label renames to "Begin" at the center "Processing" at the "Finish". But the label changes to "Processing" only at the end.

Here is my code:

This is my `ViewController's viewDidLoad()` function:

```
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        label.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 20)
        label.text = "Begin"
        label.textColor = UIColor.black

        view.addSubview(label)

        Alamofire.request("http://google.com").responseData(completionHandler: {
            res in

            if let stCode = res.response?.statusCode {
                if stCode == 200 {
                    self.label.text = "Rename"

                    print("Rename")

                    // Here I do some processing. put sleep for test
                    sleep(10)

                    print("Should be modified 10 seconds earlier")
                }
            }
        })
```

My label's text changes to "Rename" only after 10 seconds. I need it to change at the beginning.

My log:

```
Rename (I need it to change here.)
Should be modified 10 seconds earlier (Here label changes after 10 seconds)
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Comment: @SakirSherasiya I edited my question. Tell my what you don't understand

Comment: @BegmuhammetKakabayev do you want to perform any operation after 10 seconds ?

Comment: @SahilManchanda Shortly. I perform some operations in completionHandler and it takes some time. About 10 seconds. I want to show percentage of completion of process. But UI doesn't get updated. For example: At the beginning of the process label renames to "Begin" at the center "Processing" at the "Finish". But the label changes to "Processing" only at the end.

Answer (score 1):

As per discussion in comments 
when **stCode == 200** then execute your very next line change the label text then use this

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
   ///perform your heavy task here(your 10 sec task)
  ///Upon completion of your task then in following queue    
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        ///change your label text here of completion 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UI operations must be performed on main thread, so use

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.label.text = "Rename"
}
```

Comment: And I read somewhere that Alamofire completionHandler works on main thread